# new to dbt and trying to learn how to execute procedure using dbt but getting error

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

```
create or replace procedure output_message(message varchar)
returns varchar not null
language sql
as
begin
  return message;
end;

call output_message('Hello World');
```

error I'm getting:

```
Database Error in model my_first_dbt_model (models/example/my_first_dbt_model.sql)
  001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
  syntax error line 2 at position 7 unexpected 'create'.

  syntax error line 3 at position 0 unexpected 'returns'.
  compiled SQL at target/run/dbt_project/example/my_first_dbt_model.sql
```

[image: getting this error]

Comment: You might want to give this a look: https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/how-to-let-dbt-to-execute-sql-command-instead-of-create-table-object/2164

Comment: You can customize your code using materialization [link](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/legacy/creating-new-materializations) and I have followed a [link](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/legacy/creating-new-materializations) to create ddl objects. You need to write macros for that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put code for a stored procedure in a model file (any .sql file in your models directory). dbt assumes that a model file contains a single `select` statement; it then wraps that `select` statement in DDL (usually a `create table my_model as (...)` statement), depending on your materialization config for that model.

[Macros](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros/#macros) are more flexible. Generally, Stored Procedures aren't part of the dbt workflow, but there are some valid use-cases for them (along with UDFs).

You can create a `output_message.sql` file in your `macros` directory, and use the code you provided, wrapping it in a macro definition, like:

```sql
{% macro output_message(msg) %}
create or replace procedure output_message(message varchar)
returns varchar not null
language sql
as
begin
  return message;
end;

call output_message(msg);
{% endmacro %}
```

You can then call that macro in a post-hook or by using [run-operation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/run-operation):

```bash
dbt run-operation output_message --args "{'msg': 'Hello World!'}"
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the result of the stored procedure in the model?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your code using materialization [link](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/legacy/creating-new-materializations) and I have followed a [link](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/legacy/creating-new-materializations) to create ddl objects. You need to write macros for that.

Comment: Do you have your code public somewhere? It really looks like some cool stuff